# Error al momento de usar react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

estoy empezando con react js y como ejrcicio quería generar componentes de react y presentarlos en pantalla pero el tema es que me genera un error que al chico de youtube no.

Este es el codigo html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="react.css">
    <title>Learning React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The IT personal</h1>
    <div id="img-box">
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/57.jpg" alt="">
        <strong>Lorena</strong>
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/55.jpg" alt="">
        <strong>Ana</strong>
    </div>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="react.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

y este el React(en teoría)

```
const $app=document.getElementById("app")
const avatar = props =>{
    const src= "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/${props.id}.jpg" 
    return(
        <picture>
            <img src={src}></img>
            <strong>{props.name}</strong>
        </picture>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <avatar id={5} name="Pilar" />
    </div>
)
```

Y por ultimo me salta este error en la consola de firefox
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que se agregue otro componente(otra imagen, otro nombre) pero por algun motivo me da ese error.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Una pregunta, `<img src={src}></img>` es un componente que has creado y esta en un archivo aparte o, es la etiqueta img de toda la vida? Porque de ser la segunda, tienes tags de mas, debería ser así `<img src={src} />`

Answer (score 2):

Sugiero que revises la sintaxis del código original, pues el código que compartes tiene algunos detalles.

#### Template literals

La siguiente línea no tiene bien definido el template literals:

```
const src= "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/${props.id}.jpg"
```

Debería estar así:

```
const src= `https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/${props.id}.jpg`
```

#### Nombres de componentes en Mayuscula

Los nombres de los componentes React siempre van con Mayúscula:

```
const avatar = props =>{
   //codigo...
}
```

Debería ir así:

```
const Avatar = props =>{
   //codigo...
}
```

#### Target DOM node

Finalmente, no hay definido un target en el método `ReactDOM.render`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <avatar id={5} name="Pilar" />
    </div>,
    //aqui no hay target
)
```

Debería estar configurado así:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>
        <Avatar id={5} name="Pilar" /></div>,
        document.getElementById('app')
)
```

---

Demo:

```js
const Avatar = props =>{
    const src= `https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/${props.id}.jpg` 
    return(
        <picture>
            <img src={src}></img>
            <strong>{props.name}</strong>
        </picture>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<div>
        <Avatar id={5} name="Pilar" /></div>,
        document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

#### Actualización: Transpiler Babel

Además de tener los siguientes CDN envueltos entre la etiqueta `head` en el archivo `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
```

Asegurate de tener el de [Babel](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Luego, hay que indicar el tipo de script que se va a cargar en `index.html`, que es el archivo donde se tiene el código de reactJS (en este ejemplo supongo que lo tienes en una carpeta llamada `js->index.js`):

```
<script
        type="text/babel"
        src="./js/index.js">
    </script>
```

---

Si aún no te funciona, pues busca un mejor tutorial, lo recomendable es empezar con el template [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda